# Can't perform what seems like a simple HTTP POST to openweathermap.org

Tags: angular, post, cors, openweathermap, preflight

My function in an Angular service component to POST a request to create a new weather station with openweathermap.org:

```ts
registerStation(registerWeatherStation: RegisterWeatherStation): Observable<Response> {
let params = JSON.stringify(registerWeatherStation)
console.log("params: ",params)
let header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header })
let url = this.servUrl + 'stations?appid=' + this.weatherAppId
return this
    .http
    .post(url, params, options)
}
```

This is from Chrome's Developer Tools Network Tab showing activity triggered by the above function. I think this shows my preflight request, preflight response from openweathermap.org, and my request headers:

```
Preflight Request???  
request url: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations?appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
Request Method: OPTIONS  
Status Code: 404 Not Found  
Remote Address: 162.243.53.59:80  
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade  

Response Headers  
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true  
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE  
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  
Connection: keep-alive  
Content-Length: 42  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
Date: Thu, 24 May 2018 19:57:00 GMT  
Server: openresty  

Request Headers  
Accept: */*  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9  
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type  
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST  
Connection: keep-alive  
Host: api.openweathermap.org  
Origin: http://localhost:54270  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

This is Postman's code snippet of the POST I performed that got a valid response from openweathermap.org:

```
POST /data/3.0/stations?appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.openweathermap.org
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 25e03224-a9e7-43af-9757-dc37c41af780

{"external_id":"Paula's_Ranch_1","name":"Paula's Ranch Weather","latitude":xx.155012,"longitude":-xxx.976649,"altitude":100}
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I perform the post from my backend?

Comment: Yeah I think you must do the POST from your backend instead. Why: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations doesn’t seem to actually be fully CORS-enabled. Specific problem: while responses from that include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, it unfortunately doesn’t handle the CORS preflight OPTIONS request right. And there’s no way to get around that, because in order to make POST requests to that API endpoint, you must add the `Content-Type: application/json` header to the request. But adding that is what triggers browsers to send the OPTIONS, which that endpoint doesn’t handle

Comment: Thanks. I started moving the stuff to the server side last night which is ok because I needed to go there anyways to add and remove stuff to the DB. I'll be able to finish and test after I get back home today. I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Moving my POST and GET requests to server side code resolved this issue. I also used restsharp.netcore. Clean and simple.