# 405 method not allowed using Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat, cors, http-status-code-405

I am new to web development and having this issue for some time. I tried a lot of things that were suggested on SO and elsewhere, but no luck. Anyways, i'll explain what I am doing.

I am trying a simple exercise where I have a simple HTML page that accepts a city name and on clicking the submit button, will show me the weather of that city. The HTML code is as below:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input id="city" type="text" name="city">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="submitButton" type="button" name="submitButton" value="Get weather!" onclick="send()">
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CityWeather.js"></script>
</body>
```

This HTML file makes a call to my JS script which will handle the call to the API of OpenWeatherMap and display the results. Code for the JS is as below(please note I have purposely omitted the api_key but the actual URL does have it):

```
function send() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&APPID=<api_key>", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var jsonResponseText = xhttp.responseText;
    //var response = JSON.parse(jsonResponseText);
    console.log(xhttp.readyState);
    console.log(xhttp.status);
    console.log(jsonResponseText);
}
```

Now, when I first tried obtaining the results by just launching the HTML file, I got CORS issue and I realized that I should not be making the call to the API via the file URL(file://). So I downloaded Tomcat 9.0 and placed both, the HTML and JS files, inside the webapps folder of Tomcat. I then started Tomcat and launched the page. However, I get the exceptions mentioned below:

```
OPTIONS http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&APPID=<api_key> 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Failed to load http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&APPID=<api_key>: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.
```

I tried updating the CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml file with the entries below,

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

restarted the server and tried it again but still no luck. Can someone help me by pointing what needs to be done? I am using Chrome for this exercise. I tried using IE as well but no luck.

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried changing the api call. Instead of using the openweathermap api, I tried using the GIT API to get my repos.

```
function send() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/users/bhavyas66", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send();
    var jsonResponseText = xhttp.responseText;
    //var response = JSON.parse(jsonResponseText);
    console.log(xhttp.readyState);
    console.log(xhttp.status);
    console.log(jsonResponseText);
}
```

In this case, I didnt get the exceptions above, but the state is stuck at 1 and status printed is 0. The response is also empty. However, when I open the Chrome Network window, I can see that there is response under the Preview tab

Comment: Why are you adding a 'Content-type: application/json' header to a GET request? Adding that header to the request has no effect other than to trigger browsers to make a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. Remove that header from your request.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what CORS config you do on your own server. See the comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518345/cant-perform-what-seems-like-a-simple-http-post-to-openweathermap-org#comment88053824_50518345. You must do the request from your backend instead. You’re making a request to the openweathermap.org API, which doesn’t handle the CORS preflight OPTIONS request right. And if when make requests to that API, you add a 'Content-Type: application/json' header to the request, that triggers browsers to send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request, which that API doesn’t handle

Answer (score 0):

try "POST" method，405 errors often appear at the same time as the POST method